# python ctypes cast get null string

Tags: python, casting, ctypes

python ctypes cast get null string

`b` is address

if `b_v.value` is a common character, this is normal.
But if `b`'s content is hex like "1122001314"  Long as it contains hex "00"
the result maybe is 1122  the 001314 should be lose

Now I want get all content "1122001314". Please give me some method thanks.

the code is:

```
b_v=ctypes.cast(b,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))

print binascii.b2a_hex(b_v.value)
```

example:

```
import ctypes
import binascii

va=binascii.a2b_hex('1212273031003535')
tt=ctypes.create_string_buffer(va)
b=ctypes.addressof(tt)
b_v=ctypes.cast(b,ctypes.c_char_p)
print binascii.b2a_hex(b_v.value)
```

now the result is :`"1212273031"`

i want the result is `"1212273031003535"`

Comment: Weclome to Stackoverflow. Please try to improve the wording on your question, or give a concrete code-example that illustrates what you want (input and expected output). It is very hard to understand your question.

Comment: the example code has be complementaryd

Answer (score 2):

In the line `tt=ctypes.create_string_buffer(va)` You are building a string_buffer from a hexadecimal representation of data (binary data) and It's wrong, because c string terminates with first 0-value character. So your data breaks.
Fortunately ctypes serves raw-data in addition to string value, so with `tt.raw` you can access your original data and you can use `binascii.b2a_hex(tt.raw)`, but I'm not sure It's useful for you or not.

If you want to run `b=ctypes.addressof(tt)` and pass the address to somewhere else and then retrieve data from address by `b_v=ctypes.cast(b,ctypes.c_char_p)`, I should say It's not possible with string_buffer type because your data is not text, It's a binary data and you can't store it in a string_buffer and then access to it with It's address.

You can retrieve data with knowing b if you know length of data too, Try this:

```
b, l = ctypes.addressof(tt), len(tt) - 1 # l - 1, because there is one extra byte for terminator NULL

#Somewhere else:
b_v=ctypes.cast(b, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char * l))
print binascii.b2a_hex(b_v.contents)
```

Comment: binascii.b2a_hex(tt.raw)  is useful  but Only through b get content

Comment: b_v=ctypes.cast(b,ctypes.c_char_p)  and  this line can be changed

Comment: You can retrieve data using b, If and only if you know length of data, I had added an example to my answer

Comment: very very very thanks MostafaR  thanks  your method is usefull i love you  ^_^

Comment: you could also try: [`type(tt).from_address(b)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543675/how-to-convert-pointer-to-c-array-to-python-array) though it leaves terminating NUL in the data

Comment: `create_string_buffer` takes an optional size when the data contains a null byte: `ctypes.create_string_buffer(va,len(va))`.

Comment: `type(tt)` is equivalent to `ctypes.c_char * len(tt)`.

Comment: It's true, `type(tt)` is same with `ctypes.c_char * len(tt)` But I think the problem is retrieving data somewhere else, and maybe passing type(tt) is not easy - Imagine a text-based API -, so passing an integer - `len(tt)` - will be a better idea.

Comment: MostafaR is right,passing type(tt) is not easy,only through (b) , thanks MostafaR,My porject use your code