# C++ vector to Python 3.3

Tags: c++, python, cython, cpython

I would like to get a python list, say, `[1,2,3,4]`, from a C++ script. I wrote the C++ script, which returns a vector.

How to connect the ends without SWIG/SIP/Cython/and others?

Could it be easier to just compile the C++ to an .exe or elf file and then call from command line, have the .exe create a .txt containing a vector and read it in with python?

My point is, I only need a really small function from C++ to do the heavy calculations on huge data. What would be the least painful and shortest method to do just this?

**EDIT:**
To give an example. Python will give a filename string to C++ ("foo.txt"), which will then read the context of the file (200,000 rows by 300 columns), count the missings and then return to Python the amount of missings per row. This yields a list of 200,000 numbers. 
How to have this communication between both of them?

Just for completeness, this is what I am still wondering about how to go about:

- Pass python filename string to C++
- Receive python string in C++
- DONE Create vector in C++
- Return vector to Python
- Receive vector in Python

Comment: It is likely that most of the time will be spent in C++ parsing the input file so it doesn't matter from the time performance point of you  view how you would communicate with Python. Invoking C++ function from Python in the same process (e.g., [using `ctypes`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7543675/4279) or even easier using Cython) is a cleaner solution but it might be simpler for you just to pipe data between two processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably moot now, and I posted something similar on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885344/how-to-handle-c-return-type-stdvectorint-in-python-ctypes), but I've adapted this version for Python 3.3 and C++ rather than Python 2.7 and C.

If you want to get back a Python list object, and since you're building a list which could potentially be very long (200,000 items), it's probably more efficient to build the Python list in the C++ code, rather than building a `std::vector` and then converting that to a Python list later on.

Based on the code in your other question, I'd suggest using something like this...

```
// foo.cpp
#include <python3.3/Python.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    PyObject* foo(const char* FILE_NAME)
    {
        string line;
        ifstream myfile(FILE_NAME);
        PyObject* result = PyList_New(0);

        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            PyList_Append(result, PyLong_FromLong(1));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

...compiled with...

```
$ g++ -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo.cpp -lpython3.3m
```

...and an example of usage...

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> foo = CDLL('./foo.so')
>>> foo.foo.restype = py_object
>>> foo.foo(b'foo.cpp')
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

...although if you need to convert an existing `std::vector` to a Python list, you can pre-allocate the memory needed by the Python list by passing the length of the vector into [`PyList_New()`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/list.html#PyList_New), and then use [`PyList_SetItem()`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/list.html#PyList_SetItem) instead of [`PyList_Append()`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/list.html#PyList_Append).

The only other methods I can think of would be...

1. To pre-allocate a block of RAM in Python, and have the C++ function fill in the values, like in qarma's answer, but you'd have to know in advance how much RAM to allocate. You could just pick an arbitrary value, but given that the number of lines in the file isn't known in advance, this number may be way too large or way too small.
2. To heap-allocate the `std::vector` in C++, and return a pointer to the first element, and the number of elements, but you'd have to write a second function to free the RAM once you were done with it.

Either way, you still have the overhead of converting the 'returned' array into a Python list, so you may as well do it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Define your entry point `extern "C"` and use `ctypes`.

Here's an example to get you started, data is passed from Python, C++ code sorts the data, and Python gets back the result:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <algorithm>

extern "C" {
    void foo(float* arr, size_t len);
}

void foo(float* arr, size_t len)
{
    // if arr is input, convert to C++ array

    // crazy C++ code here
    std::sort(arr, arr+len);

    // if arr is output, convert C++ array to arr
}
```

Compile your code into a shared object (libxxx.so on linux, libxxx.dll on win, libxxx.dylib on osx), then load it dynamically and pass data in/out via ctypes:

```
import ctypes
import posix

# Darwin .dylib; Linux .so; Windows .dll; use sys.platform() for runtime detection
libxxx = ctypes.CDLL("./libxxx.so")
libxxx.foo.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float), ctypes.c_size_t]
libxxx.foo.restype = None

data = ctypes.ARRAY(ctypes.c_float, 100)()

# write someting into data[x]
import random
for i in range(100): data[i] = random.random()
print data[:3], "...", data[-3:]

libxxx.foo(data, len(data))

# read out from data[x]
print data[:3], "...", data[-3:]
```

Great thing about `ctypes` is that it's bundled with Python since 2.5, you don't need any additional libraries.

If you want to use something more advanced, have a look at `cffi`.

Comment: And a pleasant side-effect, GIL is released while your C++ function executes, which means you could split your workload into chunks and use your multicore processor to the max. In this case, I recommend working with threads in Python land. Threading in C++ only if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Excellent answer all around!

Comment: +1 for ctypes. If I understand the question correctly then the function should be `int* filter_file(const char* filename, int* result_array, size_t* result_size)` i.e., the size of the result is unknown before the function call. The function returns possibly `realloc`ed `result_array` or a new `malloc`'ed array if None is passed (the caller must free it). `result_size` can be passed using `ctypes.byref()`. To convert the returned pointer to a numpy array: [`a = np.frombuffer(cast(result_array, POINTER(c_int*result_size.value)).contents)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7555971/4279).

Comment: btw, don't use `posix` directly, use `os` module instead (either way `uname()` is documented as Unix-only). You could use `sys.platform.startswith("linux")` instead. You should probably leave `mode` at the default value.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks, both uname/platform and mode are valid corrections. feel free to edit :)

Comment: I am sorry to ask for it, but it would really be a really nice complete answer if it had some extra comments explaining what it is doing. I am already really happy that it works, but it's still hard to grasp what's going on. If you'd be willing to clarify more, no doubt I'll award the bounty. Oh and thanks for the multithreading suggestion!

Comment: What about the string that could be passed in?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Could you perhaps edit, as far as I can see you make some good points!

Comment: `ctypes.CDLL` loads a shared object, same way as `dlopen` does in C and returns a handle. `library.symbol` is a shortcut to access a symbol exported by that shared object. If a symbol is a global variable, it can be read and written. If it's a function, it can be called. ctypes/dlopen cannot guess `argtypes` and `restype` for you, these should be set unless defaults are exactly what you need.
To pass a C-style, NULL-terminated string, use argtype `ctypes.c_char_p` and Python's strings will be converted automatically.
http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#fundamental-data-types

Comment: @qarma So it is possible to xxx.foo(ctypes._char_p(filename)) to pass a string with path and filename to the .dll/.so? Also, why are we using void? It's only a pointer then? Is that good?

Comment: there's no need or benefit from explicit cast here, for example `int printf(const char*)` can be called implicitly as `libc.printf("blah")` (return defaults to int and arguments to natural C type for Python "blah", a C string).I advise you to call it explicitly like this: `libc.printf.restype = int; libc.printf.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]; libc.printf("blah")` then if you supply a wrong argument by accident, e.g. `None` or `123` ctypes will raise an exception and not die with segmentation fault.

Comment: @Dualinity: if we can assume that the size of the result is known in Python *before* calling the function the the answer is fine except for few minor details.

Comment: @qarma: `ctypes.ARRAY` is deprecated, you could use `ArrayType = ctypes.c_float * 100; array = ArrayType()` instead. You should pass bytes to `char*` function in Python 3 i.e., `libc.printf(b"abc\n")` (if `printf.argtypes` is defined; `ctypes` should raise `ArgumentError`)

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track.

Do you have two executables going?

Better would be to save it to an intermediate file. Lock the file, write to it from your C++ code. Unlock and read it from Python.

If you just want to run from python, you can always look into extending python:

[Extending Python with C++](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)

There's also the option of doing it through sockets, though this may be a bit of overkill if all you want to do is pass lists.

Comment: Extending Python with C++ is a reference to Python 2.x. Even the Python 3 version is not what I'm looking for: it has the tutorial for C code.

Comment: It will work in C++, you just have to define a few things. Read the part about making it work with C++. But yes, the examples will be in straight C code, this is just the nature of Python. Doesn't mean it will not work with C++.

Comment: Would you advice for or against the other answer below about subprocesses?

Comment: This depends. How many times do you plan on executing the external c++ file? It seems you're doing this for efficiency reasons? If so, Python is fast. Maybe not as fast as c++ but you'll end up losing any performance benefits in these intermediate steps.

Comment: Efficiency is indeed key. I updated the answer, and I'm now putting out a bounty for an answer that can give even more direction (I tried understanding but I can't really follow what's going on in the link).

Comment: Oh and I do not have 2 executables. I only brought this idea up because I'm so frustrated not getting the "proper" way done. I prefer to have a C++ as a custom module for Python.

Comment: @Dualinity: Fair enough. Although I think you'll find Python plenty fast do do what you need. If it is even possible to be more efficient, your answer will be writing a python extension. Have you tried this solution in python? If it is running slow, it may be the algorithm to blame for the slow speeds.

Comment: It's supposed to be part of an application. Any second counts. If there is a speed gain in C++, I want it. That's where I am coming from. You really suppose there will be barely any difference?

Comment: @Dualinity: simple arithmetic on Python numbers (without using `numpy` arrays) can be 20x-200x times slower than similar code in C++.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the subprocess module in python to read the output from your c++ exe file.
For example:

c++ file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4};
    cout<<"[";
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<",";
    cout<<a[3]<<"]";
    return 0;
}
```

then your python script will be:

```
import subprocess
a=subprocess.check_output("c++compiledfile")
l=eval(a)
print l
```

Comment: you could use `ast.literal_eval` (or even `json` module) instead of `eval` here. It might be more effective to write the C array as binary and read from Python using `array` module.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with strings in the interprocess communication:

use the subprocess.check_output() function in Python to check the C++ program's output, and pass the filename as an argument:

Python's code:

```
import subprocess
from time import clock


ti=clock()
txt_fname='foo.txt'
# pass the filename string to a c++ program, and receive vector in python
output=subprocess.check_output(["./prog", txt_fname])
result = eval(output)   # convert the str_result to a vector/list
tf=clock()

print(result)
print(format(tf-ti, '.3f'))
```

C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // receive python string in c++
    char* txt_fname = argv[1];

/*  // read matrix from file in c++
    FILE *f_matrix = fopen(txt_fname, "r");
    // ... [done by the question's author!]
    if (f_matrix!=NULL){
        fclose(f_matrix);
    }*/

    // create the vector in c++
    int n=200000;
    std::vector<int> vect(n);
    // or:  int vect[];
    // ... [done by the question's author!]

    // return the vector to python
    std::cout << "[";
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        std::cout << vect[i] << ", ";
    std::cout << "]";

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** to add the timers and to replace "ast.literal_eval()" with "eval()", because in fact eval() in this case is faster and it is compatible with python 3.3.

Comment: Really interesting. How about its speed?

Comment: It's "fast", you can run that code straight forwardly. This Python script that calls the C++ program and waits for it runs in approximately 0.470 seconds, in my laptop. Is that time good for you? I'm going to add the timers in the script...