# How to handle C++ return type std::vector<int> in Python ctypes?

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I cannot find how ctypes will bridge the gap between `std::vector` and Python; no where on the internet is the combination mentioned. Is this bad practice, does it not exist or am I missing something?

**C++** :  xxx.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
extern "C" std::vector<int> foo(const char* FILE_NAME)
{
    string line;
    std::vector<int> result;
    ifstream myfile(FILE_NAME);
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
      result.push_back(1);
    }

    return(result);
}
```

**Python:**   xxx.py

```
import ctypes
xxx = ctypes.CDLL("./libxxx.so")
xxx.foo.argtypes = ??????
xxx.foo.restype = ??????
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9084111/951890

Comment: I just came from that page, it's related as much as a Python Numpy question is related to another Python Numpy question. The mentioned thread does not help in this case. Other suggestions?

Comment: Note that it does mention std::vector, but in the sense of connecting it to a list in python. My understanding is that with ctypes, Python would be able to work with a ctypes-object?

Comment: It isn't so much that it's related to using std::vector as it is to using C++ in general.  C++ just isn't supported by ctypes in any meaningful way.  It is best to create C functions with C-style interfaces.

Comment: You could probably hack something together which works, but you'd be better off creating an array of `int` and returning a pointer to that instead.

Comment: @Aya and one shouldn't forget to free the memory allocated for the array when it's not needed any more. Another approach: the array is allocated in Python code, and C/C++ library just fills it with values.

Comment: @VaughnCato Good point, though I am hoping for some options using C++.

Comment: @Inspired Well, it's difficult to advise on the best approach for this case, since it seems a little pointless to return a `vector<int>` of length equal to the number of lines in a file, where every value is `1`, or an array equivalent thereof.

Comment: @Aya, I actually do not see a reason why I wouldn't use an array instead. I just started with a vector first, but in this case an array might make more sense? (the value 1 will be based on another function, but that's another story, and there will be 200,000 of them)

Comment: @Dualinity It might help to elaborate on what you're trying to achieve here, since the code in the question doesn't seem to have any useful application.

Comment: @Aya It will count the amount of times "NA" will occur on each line (without quotes).

Comment: @Dualinity I'm not particularly familiar with the STL, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array-c) suggests it's trivial to cast a `vector<T>` to a `T*`. The problem here is that if the `vector` is stack-allocated, it may not be valid after returning the pointer, and the problem with passing in a pointer from Python is that you won't know in advance how much memory to allocate. Is there some reason why you can't just write that particular C++ function in Python?

Comment: @Aya The particular reason is that speed is important. I'm creating an application that should be able to handle big data. On 200,000 rows the missings have to be counted on 300 values (200k by 300 matrix). I believe, but correct me if I'm wrong, that C++ will be significantly faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The particular reason is that speed is important. I'm creating an
>   application that should be able to handle big data. On 200,000 rows
>   the missings have to be counted on 300 values (200k by 300 matrix). I
>   believe, but correct me if I'm wrong, that C++ will be significantly
>   faster.

Well, if you're reading from a large file, your process is going to be mostly IO-bound, so the timings between Python and C probably won't be significantly different.

The following code...

```
result = []
for line in open('test.txt'):
    result.append(line.count('NA'))
```

...seems to run just as fast as anything I can hack together in C, although it's using some [optimized algorithm](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/687295c6c8f2/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h) I'm not really familiar with.

It takes less than a second to process 200,000 lines, although I'd be interested to see if you can write a C function which is significantly faster.

---

**Update**

If you want to do it in C, and end up with a Python list, it's probably more efficient to use the [Python/C API](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/) to build the list yourself, rather than building a `std::vector` then converting to a Python list later on.

An example which just returns a list of integers from 0 to 99...

```
// hack.c

#include <python2.7/Python.h>

PyObject* foo(const char* filename)
{
    PyObject* result = PyList_New(0);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        PyList_Append(result, PyInt_FromLong(i));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Compiled with...

```
$ gcc -c hack.c -fPIC
$ ld -o hack.so -shared hack.o -lpython2.7
```

Example of usage...

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> dll = CDLL('./hack.so')
>>> dll.foo.restype = py_object
>>> dll.foo('foo')
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...]
```

Comment: I kind of noticed this as well just now running similar code, it took around 8 seconds for Python to do it. However, I am still curious to the correct C++ way to do it.

Comment: @Dualinity How do you want the result in Python? As a Python list?

Comment: The 1 second is amazing. I don't care if it won't be so helpful for others looking for a C++ answer, this is impressive. Makes me wonder when I would indeed need C++.

Comment: @Dualinity See updated answer for a C-based example. Should be trivial to use similar code in C++.

Answer (score 28):

Whether or not this approach actually provides faster execution time, I'll explain a bit about how you could go about doing it. Basically, create a pointer to a C++ `vector` which can interface with Python through C functions. You can then wrap the C++ code in a Python class, hiding the implementation details of `ctypes`.

I included what I thought would be helpful magic methods to include in the Python class. You can choose to remove them or add more to suit your needs. The destructor is important to keep though.

### C++

```c
// vector_python.cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void foo(vector<int>* v, const char* FILE_NAME){
    string line;
    ifstream myfile(FILE_NAME);
    while (getline(myfile, line)) v->push_back(1);
}

extern "C" {
    vector<int>* new_vector(){
        return new vector<int>;
    }
    void delete_vector(vector<int>* v){
        cout << "destructor called in C++ for " << v << endl;
        delete v;
    }
    int vector_size(vector<int>* v){
        return v->size();
    }
    int vector_get(vector<int>* v, int i){
        return v->at(i);
    }
    void vector_push_back(vector<int>* v, int i){
        v->push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Compile it as a shared library. On Mac OS X this might look like,

```
g++ -c -fPIC vector_python.cpp -o vector_python.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-install_name,vector_python_lib.so -o vector_python_lib.so vector_python.o
```

### Python

```
from ctypes import *

class Vector(object):
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('vector_python_lib.so') # class level loading lib
    lib.new_vector.restype = c_void_p
    lib.new_vector.argtypes = []
    lib.delete_vector.restype = None
    lib.delete_vector.argtypes = [c_void_p]
    lib.vector_size.restype = c_int
    lib.vector_size.argtypes = [c_void_p]
    lib.vector_get.restype = c_int
    lib.vector_get.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_int]
    lib.vector_push_back.restype = None
    lib.vector_push_back.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_int]
    lib.foo.restype = None
    lib.foo.argtypes = [c_void_p]

    def __init__(self):
        self.vector = Vector.lib.new_vector()  # pointer to new vector

    def __del__(self):  # when reference count hits 0 in Python,
        Vector.lib.delete_vector(self.vector)  # call C++ vector destructor

    def __len__(self):
        return Vector.lib.vector_size(self.vector)

    def __getitem__(self, i):  # access elements in vector at index
        if 0 <= i < len(self):
            return Vector.lib.vector_get(self.vector, c_int(i))
        raise IndexError('Vector index out of range')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '[{}]'.format(', '.join(str(self[i]) for i in range(len(self))))

    def push(self, i):  # push calls vector's push_back
        Vector.lib.vector_push_back(self.vector, c_int(i))

    def foo(self, filename):  # foo in Python calls foo in C++
        Vector.lib.foo(self.vector, c_char_p(filename))
```

You can then test it out in the interpreter (`file.txt` just consists of three lines of jibberish).

```
>>> from vector import Vector
>>> a = Vector()
>>> a.push(22)
>>> a.push(88)
>>> a
[22, 88]
>>> a[1]
88
>>> a[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "vector.py", line 30, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError('Vector index out of range')
IndexError: Vector index out of range
>>> a.foo('file.txt')
>>> a
[22, 88, 1, 1, 1]
>>> b = Vector()
>>> ^D
destructor called in C++ for 0x1003884d0
destructor called in C++ for 0x10039df10
```

Comment: Super awesome answer!

Answer (score 3):

Basically, returning a C++ object from a dynamically loaded library is not a good idea. To use the C++ `vector` in Python code, you must teach Python to deal with C++ objects (and this includes binary representation of the objects which can change with new version of a C++ compiler or STL).

`ctypes` allows you to interact with a library using C types. Not C++.

Maybe the problem is solvable via `boost::python`, but it looks more reliable to use plain C for the interaction.