# C++ Constructor chaining to create/maintain an external structure

Tags: python, c++, oop, inheritance, ctypes

I am trying to use python Ctypes to interface to a C++ class I have been provided. I've gotten most everything working in terms of reading/writing member data and calling methods. But The class Im trying to exercise (call it ClassA) relies on an external Class (call it classB). see:

```
//main.cc   This is existing caller code. everything is c++ so using it is easy
include "ClassA.hh"
include "ClassB.hh"

void main() {

ClassB objB(x,y,z);

ClassA objA(a,b, &objB);

objA.DoStuff();
}
```

But I'm not ready to do the work to bind and expose classB in python via ctypes. For those who haven't used ctypes, you basically write some C bindings, and call them in python. The class A binding might look like:

```
//at the bottom of ClassA.hh
extern "C" {
    ClassA* ObjaNew(int x, int y) { return new ClassA(x,y);}
    void ObjaDoStuff(ClassA* objPtr) { objPtr->DoStuff();}
}
```

And then the calling code in python might look like

```
mylib = ctypes.cdll('mylib.so')
myPyObj = mylib.ObjaNew(5,6)   // executes ObjaNew
mylib.ObjaDoStuff(myPyObj)     // executes ObjaDoStuff
```

An important point being that python ctypes supports native-ish c types only.  Creating, Passing or Getting a class or struct or std::vector through the Ctypes interface is work. For example: this link is code that one would need to write to be able to allocate a c++ vector: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16887455/2312509

So, what I think I want to do is this:

```
//classA.hh

class ClassA{
public:
    ClassA(int a, int b, ClassB* p_objb) {  //This is the existing constructor
        ; //whatever
        m_objb = p_objb;
    }
    ClassA(int a, int b) {              // This is my new constructor
        ClassB *objB = new ClassB(x,y,z);
        ClassA(a,b,objB);
    }
```

I've done this and it compiles, but I can't actually run it yet. My concern is that objB is deallocated, because I can't see it as a member, despite it being allocated in the body of a constructor. I feel like if the call to new was being assigned to a member data pointer It would be right, because that how it works, but the assignment to a local pointer, and then passing the local pointer might fail.

I think I could maybe create a child class that inherits from both, like:

```
ClassAB: public b():public a(){
//But the A constructor still would need to NOT rely on the existence of ObjB
    m_objb = &this;
    }
```

I've not written a whole bunch of C++, so I don't know what the right answer is, But I feel like this isn't a new or novel concept.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Python, though from a C++ aspect this question got me confused. Are you trying to construct a class one way owning a B and one way not owning it. If A gets destroyed, what do you expect to happen with the B instance?

Comment: @JVApen The way the caller of A is written, A is the only thing that uses B, so from my perspective, I suppose I should have a destructor that knows whether whether or not I created/allocated B and should either delete it or not appropriately.  The python part is not super relevant, except for the notion that python's Ctypes basically supports ints, floats, chars, and pointers to each of those and void, so passing anything external to the class that isn't one of these is a PITA.

Comment: Do you need B to outlive A in that case, or can the ownership be moved into A?

Comment: I do not Need B to outlive A. I find myself wanting to refactor so that A is a child class of B.

Comment: Perfect, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this question it's obvious that you have to spend some time learning the basics of working with objects in C++.

In this case I would recommend doing the following:

```
class ClassA{
     int m_a{};
     int m_b{};
     ClassB m_objb{};
public:
    ClassA(int a, int b, ClassB &&p_objb)
        : m_a{a}
        , m_b{b}
        , m_objb{std::move(p_objb)}
    { 
    }
    ClassA(int a, int b)
       : ClassA(a, b, ClassB{x, y, z})
    {
    }
};
```

By making ClassB a member of Class a, you don't have to worry about memory allocations or ownership as this is implicit.

The calling code will look like this:

```
 ClassB objB(x,y,z);
 ClassA objA(a,b, std::move(objB));
 objA.DoStuff();
```

Or even easier:

```
 ClassA objA(a,b, ClassB(x, y, z));
 objA.DoStuff();
```

This last clearly indicates the ClassB is only needed to construct ClassA and you can't write a use after move.

If you want to learn a bit more, I can recommend another post of mine explaining the same basics to someone knowing Java: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241354/remaking-a-1998-rts-game-in-c/241647#241647

Answer (score 0):

So, What I appear to have running right now is a thin interface class:

```
//classAInterface.cc
#include "classA.hh"  // These are unchanged
#include "classB.hh"

class ClassAInterface {
public:
    ClassAInterface(int a, int b);
    ClassB *m_objb;
    ClassA *m_obja;
};
ClassAInterface(int a, int b){
    m_objb = new ClassB();
    m_obja = new ClassA(a,b,m_objb);
}

extern "C" {
    ClassAInterface* ObjaNew(int x, int y) { return new ClassAInterface(x,y);}
    void ObjaDoStuff(ClassAInterface* objIntPtr) { objIntPtr->m_obja->DoStuff();}
}

// The python is the same
mylib = ctypes.cdll('mylib.so')
myPyObj = mylib.ObjaNew(5,6)   // executes ObjaNew
mylib.ObjaDoStuff(myPyObj)     // executes ObjaDoStuff
```

This is appears to be working and allows me to not actually change the classes to which I want to interface. It has some drawbacks, as there are other unpleasantries in the way my real ClassA relies on it's caller to do certain things.

Comment: Note you also need a function to delete `myPyObj` or will have a memory leak in Python.  You might also look into wrapper generators such as [SWIG](http://swig.org/) to wrap C++ class in Python automatically.