# Force NumPy ndarray to take ownership of its memory in Cython

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

Following [this answer to "Can I force a numpy ndarray to take ownership of its memory?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18312855/396967) I attempted to use the Python C API function `PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS` through Cython's NumPy wrapper and found it is not exposed.

The following attempt to expose it manually (this is just a minimum example reproducing the failure)

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

np.import_array()

ctypedef np.int32_t DTYPE_t

cdef extern from "numpy/ndarraytypes.h":
    void PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(np.PyArrayObject *arr, int flags)

def test():
    cdef int N = 1000

    cdef DTYPE_t *data = <DTYPE_t *>malloc(N * sizeof(DTYPE_t))
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] arr = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &N, np.NPY_INT32, data)
    PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(arr, np.NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA)
```

fails with a compile error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
def test():
    cdef int N = 1000

    cdef DTYPE_t *data = <DTYPE_t *>malloc(N * sizeof(DTYPE_t))
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] arr = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &N, np.NPY_INT32, data)
    PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(arr, np.NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA)
                          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/tmp/test.pyx:19:27: Cannot convert Python object to 'PyArrayObject *'
```

**My question:** Is this the right approach to take in this case? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not, how do I force NumPy to take ownership in Cython, without going down to a C extension module?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: It did indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just have some minor errors in the interface definition. The following worked for me:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

np.import_array()

ctypedef np.int32_t DTYPE_t

cdef extern from "numpy/arrayobject.h":
    void PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(np.ndarray arr, int flags)

cdef data_to_numpy_array_with_spec(void * ptr, np.npy_intp N, int t):
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] arr = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &N, t, ptr)
    PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(arr, np.NPY_OWNDATA)
    return arr

def test():
    N = 1000

    cdef DTYPE_t *data = <DTYPE_t *>malloc(N * sizeof(DTYPE_t))
    arr = data_to_numpy_array_with_spec(data, N, np.NPY_INT32)
    return arr
```

This is my `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [Extension("_owndata", ["owndata.pyx"])]
setup(cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext}, ext_modules=ext_modules)
```

Build with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. Then verify that the data is actually owned:

```
import _owndata
arr = _owndata.test()
print arr.flags
```

Among others, you should see `OWNDATA : True`.

And *yes*, this is definitely the right way to deal with this, since `numpy.pxd` does exactly the same thing to export all the other functions to Cython.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It compiles fine, but importing the module results in a linking error, complaining about PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS. This is with numpy 1.9.1.

Comment: This solution works since numpy 1.7. Older versions lack PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS

Comment: This fails with `ImportError: ./_owndata.so: undefined symbol: PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS`

Comment: @Korem Have you use `cdef extern from "numpy/arrayobject.h"` ? And maybe you need to check if "numpy" is in your include path.

Comment: what if the data type is user defined like `my_dtype = np.dtype([('t1', np.float32), ('t2', np.uint16)])`? I realize it has a `type_num` but could not figure out how to get it in Cython. It is defined `cdef np.ndarray[mytype_t] arr` and `mytype_t` has packed float and uint16.

Comment: In `setup.py`, `Extension` should have the `include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]` parameter in my case for it to find the numpy headers.

Answer (score 7):

[@Stefan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23873586/5769463) works for most scenarios, but is somewhat fragile. Numpy uses [`PyDataMem_NEW/PyDataMem_FREE`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/c-api.array.html#memory-management) for memory-management and it is an implementation detail, that these calls are mapped to the usual [`malloc/free`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/31f19645a13ee221f037ade57f13006127aa4c46/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c#L217-L233) + some memory tracing (I don't know which effect Stefan's solution has on the memory tracing, at least it seems not to crash).

There are also more esoteric cases possible, in which `free` from numpy-library doesn't use the same memory-allocator as `malloc` in the cython code (linked against different run-times for example as in this [github-issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8253) or this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63147214/5769463)).

**The right tool to pass/manage the ownership of the data is [`PyArray_SetBaseObject`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SetBaseObject).**

First we need a python-object, which is responsible for freeing the memory. I'm using a self-made cdef-class here (mostly because of logging/demostration), but there are obviously other possiblities as well:

```
%%cython
from libc.stdlib cimport free

cdef class MemoryNanny:
    cdef void* ptr # set to NULL by "constructor"
    def __dealloc__(self):
        print("freeing ptr=", <unsigned long long>(self.ptr)) #just for debugging
        free(self.ptr)
        
    @staticmethod
    cdef create(void* ptr):
        cdef MemoryNanny result = MemoryNanny()
        result.ptr = ptr
        print("nanny for ptr=", <unsigned long long>(result.ptr)) #just for debugging
        return result

 ...
```

Now, we use a `MemoryNanny`-object as sentinel for the memory, which gets freed as soon as the parent-numpy-array gets destroyed. The code is a little bit awkward, because `PyArray_SetBaseObject` steals the reference, which is not handled by Cython automatically:

```
%%cython
...
from cpython.object cimport PyObject
from cpython.ref cimport Py_INCREF

cimport numpy as np

#needed to initialize PyArray_API in order to be able to use it
np.import_array()


cdef extern from "numpy/arrayobject.h":
    # a little bit awkward: the reference to obj will be stolen
    # using PyObject*  to signal that Cython cannot handle it automatically
    int PyArray_SetBaseObject(np.ndarray arr, PyObject *obj) except -1 # -1 means there was an error
          
cdef array_from_ptr(void * ptr, np.npy_intp N, int np_type):
    cdef np.ndarray arr = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &N, np_type, ptr)
    nanny = MemoryNanny.create(ptr)
    Py_INCREF(nanny) # a reference will get stolen, so prepare nanny
    PyArray_SetBaseObject(arr, <PyObject*>nanny) 
    return arr
...
```

And here is an example, how this functionality can be called:

```
%%cython
...
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
def create():
    cdef double *ptr=<double*>malloc(sizeof(double)*8);
    ptr[0]=42.0
    return array_from_ptr(ptr, 8, np.NPY_FLOAT64)
```

which can be used as follows:

```
>>> m =  create()
nanny for ptr= 94339864945184
>>> m.flags
...
OWNDATA : False
...
>>> m[0]
42.0
>>> del m
freeing ptr= 94339864945184
```

with results/output as expected.

**Note:** the resulting arrays doesn't really own the data (i.e. flags return `OWNDATA : False`), because the memory is owned be the memory-nanny, but the result is the same: the memory gets freed as soon as array is deleted (because nobody holds a reference to the nanny anymore).

---

`MemoryNanny` doesn't have to guard a raw C-pointer. It can be anything else, for example also a `std::vector`:

```
%%cython -+
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cdef class VectorNanny:
    #automatically default initialized/destructed by Cython:
    cdef vector[double] vec 
    @staticmethod
    cdef create(vector[double]& vec):
        cdef VectorNanny result = VectorNanny()
        result.vec.swap(vec) # swap and not copy
        return result
   
# for testing:
def create_vector(int N):
    cdef vector[double] vec;
    vec.resize(N, 2.0)
    return VectorNanny.create(vec)
```

The following test shows, that the nanny works:

```
nanny=create_vector(10**8) # top shows additional 800MB memory are used
del nanny                  # top shows, this additional memory is no longer used.
```

Answer (score 6):

The latest Cython version allows you to do with with minimal syntax, albeit slightly more overhead than the lower-level solutions suggested.

> `numpy_array = np.asarray(<np.int32_t[:10, :10]> my_pointer)`

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#coercion-to-numpy

*This alone does not pass ownership.*

Notably, a Cython array is generated with this call, via [`array_cwrapper`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/05f7a479f6417716b3de2a9559f2724013af6eba/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx#L245).

This generates a `cython.array`, without allocating memory. The `cython.array` uses the `stdlib.h` [`malloc`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/05f7a479f6417716b3de2a9559f2724013af6eba/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx#L175) and [`free`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/05f7a479f6417716b3de2a9559f2724013af6eba/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx#L219) by default, so it would be expected that you use the default malloc, as well, instead of any special CPython/Numpy allocators.

`free` is only called if ownership is set for this `cython.array`, which it is by default only if it allocates data. For our case, we can manually set it via:

> `my_cyarr.free_data = True`

---

So to return a 1D array, it would be as simple as:

```py
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

# ...
    cdef cvarray cvarr = <np.int32_t[:N]> data
    cvarr.free_data = True
    return np.asarray(cvarr)
```