# How to work with 2D array returned from c function using Cython?

Tags: cython

I have had success in sending numpy arrays to c functions with Cython. Whenever I have a function in c that takes `int *` and I have some variable in python, call it`arr`, that is 1D numpy array I just call the function with `&arr[0]` and it works.

Now I'm interested in receiving a 2D array created with a c function. How can I do this? Below is what I've tried.

```
// this is the c code that returns a 2D array
int **make_array() {
  int nrows = 3;
  int ncols = 5;

  int **ret = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
  ret[0] = calloc(nrows * ncols, sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 1; i < nrows; i++) {
    ret[i] = ret[0] + i * ncols;
  }

  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
      ret[i][j] = ++count;

  return ret;
}
```

python code

```
# python code that receives the 2D array
def foo():
    cdef int nRows = 3
    cdef int nCols = 5
    cdef int[:,::1] ret = np.zeros((nRows, nCols), dtype=np.int32)
    ret = make_array()
```

This gives me the following error for the last line of the function:

```
Cannot convert 'int **' to memoryviewslice
```

If I don't create a memoryview and instead have some variable created at the point of the call to receive the output the assignment to the variable will work fine. The problem is that I still can't figure out how to work with the returned value. For example I can't do this:

```
# python code that receives the 2D array
def foo():
    cdef int nRows = 3
    cdef int nCols = 5
    ret = make_array() # works
    print(ret) # fails
```

It complaints with the same error:

```
Cannot convert 'int **' to Python object
```

How can one work with `int **` returned from a c function?

Comment: First `int **` is not a "2D array", it's a pointer of pointer to int. `int *` is not an array is a pointer to int. `cdef float[:,::1] ret = np.zeros((nRows, nCols), dtype=np.int32)` ??? I don't know use Cpython but why float is here ? I think you must tell to python what size it can use in these pointers

Comment: sorry it was supposed  to be `cdef int[:,::1] ret`, I edited now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872946/force-numpy-ndarray-to-take-ownership-of-its-memory-in-cython ?

Comment: @DavidW I have been trying to implement following that approach but so far I haven't had success. Can you take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539070/return-2d-array-created-from-a-c-function-into-python-using-cython)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As python is not capable of converting pointers from a C program I would rather advise you to use `struct` in your C code and then just return the `struct` by value like below:-

```
struct TDArray {
    int arr[3][3];
};

struct TDArray make_array() {
    struct TDArray numbers = {
        {
            {0, 1, 2},
            {3, 4, 5},
            {6, 7, 8}
        }
    };//I am hard coding it you just need utilize this approach in your code
            /* Something like
            struct TDArray numbers;
            numbers.arr[0][0]=0;
           */

    return numbers;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is good advice - there are ways of getting Python to take ownership of allocated memory, and the struct is limited a fixed array size and not a whole lot more accessible in Python that the array.

Comment: @DavidW, thanks for your advise. I am reading the link you have provided. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Abhijit Pritam that was a good starting point but there's a better method that was pointed by  DavidW [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539070/return-2d-array-created-from-a-c-function-into-python-using-cython) .  With this method we can get a numpy array directly and we're not limited to fixed size.