# Storing data using PyArray_NewFromDescr

Tags: python, cython

I use cython and I need to store the data as shown below. Earlier I used for loops to store the data from `pus_image[0]` into a 3D array but when running for `n frames` it created a bottleneck in performance. Hence I used `PyArray_NewFromDescr` to store which solves the bottleneck issue earlier faced. But the displayed images look different from the previous method, as I am not able to do increment `_puc_image += aoiStride`. Could anyone please help me solve this issue.

---

Code 1 :

```
    def LiveAquisition(self,nframes,np.ndarray[np.uint16_t,ndim = 3,mode = 'c']data):
    cdef:
        int available
        AT_64 sizeInBytes
        AT_64 aoiStride
        AT_WC string[20]
        AT_WC string1[20]
        AT_WC string2[20]
        AT_WC string3[20]
        unsigned char * pBuf
        unsigned char * _puc_image
        int BufSize
        unsigned int i, j, k, l = 0

    for i in range(nframes):
        pBuf = <unsigned char *>calloc(sizeInBytes, sizeof(unsigned char))
        AT_QueueBuffer(<AT_H>self.cameraHandle, pBuf, sizeInBytes)

        print "Frame number is :",
        print i
        response_code = AT_WaitBuffer(<AT_H>self.cameraHandle, &pBuf, &BufSize, 500)

        _puc_image = pBuf
        pus_image = <unsigned short*>pBuf
        for j in range(self.aoiWidth/self.hbin):
            pus_image = <unsigned short*>(_puc_image)
            for k in range(self.aoiHeight/self.vbin):
                data[l][j][k]  = pus_image[0]
                pus_image += 1
            _puc_image += aoiStride

    free(pBuf)
    return data
```

---

Code 2 : Using `PyArray_NewFromDescr`
Prior to which its defined as :

```
from cpython.ref cimport PyTypeObject
from python_ref cimport Py_INCREF


cdef extern from "<numpy/arrayobject.h>":
object PyArray_NewFromDescr(PyTypeObject *subtype, np.dtype descr,int nd, np.npy_intp* dims,np.npy_intp*strides,void* data, int flags, object obj)
```

---

```
    def LiveAquisition(self,nframes,np.ndarray[np.uint16_t,ndim = 3,mode = 'c']data):
    cdef:
        int available
        AT_64 sizeInBytes
        AT_64 aoiStride
        AT_WC string[20]
        AT_WC string1[20]
        AT_WC string2[20]
        AT_WC string3[20]
        unsigned char * pBuf
        unsigned char * _puc_image
        int BufSize
        unsigned int i, j, k, l = 0
        np.npy_intp dims[2]
        np.dtype dtype = np.dtype('<B')


    for i in range(nframes):
        pBuf = <unsigned char *>calloc(sizeInBytes, sizeof(unsigned char))
        AT_QueueBuffer(<AT_H>self.cameraHandle, pBuf, sizeInBytes)
        print "Frame number is :",
        print i
        response_code = AT_WaitBuffer(<AT_H>self.cameraHandle, &pBuf, &BufSize, 500)

        Py_INCREF(dtype)
        dims[0] = self.aoiWidth
        dims[1] = self.aoiHeight
        data[i,:,:] = PyArray_NewFromDescr(<PyTypeObject *> np.ndarray, np.dtype('<B'), 2,dims, NULL,pBuf, np.NPY_C_CONTIGUOUS, None)

    free(pBuf)
    return data
```

Comment: Probably minor point, but for code 1, I notice you use `data[l][j][k]` instead of `data[l, j, k]`. Not 100% sure if it matters, but does changing that change performance in any way?

Comment: You're freeing the last frame (and no others) when numpy owns the data. I also suspect you're not handling "steals a reference to descr" correctly. Why not just get a pointer from an array allocated by numpy rather than allocating it yourself?

Comment: @CodeSugeon, yes changing to `data[l, j, k]` does make a difference.Thank you 
But I still want to figure out how to make method 2 work

Comment: @DavidW, could you please elaborate a bit. A pseudo-code would be great!

Comment: `pBuff = &data[i,0,0]` should allow your capture functions to write directly into data (I think...)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few *large* errors in the way you're doing this. However, what you're doing is totally unnecessary, and there's a much simpler approach. 
You can simply allocate the data using Numpy, and get the address of the first element of that array:

```
# earlier
cdef unsigned char[:,::1] p
# in loop
p = np.array((self.aoiWidth,self.aoiHeight),dtype=np.uint8)
pbuf = &p[0,0] # address of first element of p

# code goes here
data[i,:,:] = p
```

---

Errors in what you're doing:

1. `pBuf = <unsigned char *>calloc(sizeInBytes, sizeof(unsigned char))`

   Here, `sizeInBytes` is uninitialized, and therefore the size you allocate with be arbitrary.
2. `PyArray_NewFromDescr` *steals a reference* to the `descr` argument. This means that it does not increment the reference count of the argument. The line

   ```
   PyArray_NewFromDescr(<PyTypeObject *> np.ndarray, np.dtype('<B'), ...)
   ```

   will be translated as Cython to something like

   ```
   temp_dtype = np.dtype('<B') # refcount 1
   PyArray_NewFromDescr(<PyTypeObject *> np.ndarray, temp_dtype, ...)
   # temp_dtype refcount is still 1
   Py_DECREF(temp_dtype) # Cython's own cleanup
   # temp_dtype has now been destroyed, but is still being used by your array
   ```

   It looks like you copied some code that dealt with this correctly (`Py_INCREF(dtype)`, which was then passed to `PyArray_NewFromDescr`), but chose to ignore that and create your own temporary object.
3. `PyArray_NewFromDescr` does not own the data. Therefore you are responsible for deallocating it once it has been used (and only when you're sure it's no longer needed). You only do one `free`, after the loop, so you are leaking almost all the memory you allocated. Either put the `free` in the loop, or [modify the `OWNDATA` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872946/force-numpy-ndarray-to-take-ownership-of-its-memory-in-cython) to give your new array ownership of your array.

---

In summary, unless you have a good understanding of the Python C API I recommend don't using `PyArray_NewFromDescr` and using numpy arrays to allocate your data instead.