# C-Numpy: How to create fixed-width ndarray of strings from existing data

Tags: python, c++, numpy, python-c-api

I'm writing a Python extension module in C++ with Boost Python. I want to return numpy arrays from the module to Python. It works well with numeric datatypes like `double` but at one point I need to create a `string` array from existing data.

For numeric arrays I used `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` which worked well, but since strings are not fixed length I used `PyArray_New` where I can pass in the itemsize which is in my case 4. Here's a minimal example:

```cpp
bool initNumpy()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    import_array();
    return true;
}

class Foo {
    public:            
        Foo() {
            initNumpy();
            data.reserve(10);
            data = {"Rx", "Rx", "Rx", "RxTx", "Tx", "Tx", "Tx", "RxTx", "Rx", "Tx"};                
        }

        PyObject* getArray() {
            npy_intp dims[] = { data.size() };            
            return (PyObject*)PyArray_New(&PyArray_Type, 1, dims, NPY_STRING, NULL, &data[0], 4, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA, NULL);
        }
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> data;             
};
```

I expect the output of `getArray()`to be equal to the output of `numpy.array(["Rx", "Rx" ...], dtype="S4")` which is:

```py
array([b'Rx', b'Rx', b'Rx', b'RxTx', b'Tx', b'Tx', b'Tx', b'RxTx', b'Rx',
       b'Tx'], dtype='|S4')
```

but it looks like this:

```py
array([b'Rx', b'', b'\xcc\xb3b\xd9', b'\xfe\x07', b'\x02', b'', b'\x0f',
       b'', b'Rx\x00\x03', b''], dtype='|S4')
```

I tried playing around with the `npy_intp const* strides` argument because I think the issue are the memory blocks of the underlying data. Unfortunately it didnt achieve my desired results.

I'm using Microsoft Build Tools 2017, Boost python, distutils and Python 3.7 to build the extension.

Comment: `std::string` tends to be structured as a pointer to an array + some metadata, so passing the location of an array of strings to Numpy is pretty meaningless. I'm not immediately sure how I'd solve the problem though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `PyArray_New`, the passed data must have the one memory-layout, which is expected by the numpy-array. It was the case for such simple data-types as `np.float64`, but is not the case for `std::vector<std::string>` and `dtype='|S4'`.

First, what memory layout does `PyArray_New` expect for `|S4`?

Let's choose as example

```
array([b'Rx', b'RxTx', b'T'], dtype='|S4')
```

the expected memory layout would be:

```
| R| x|\0|\0| R| x| T| x| T|\0|\0|\0|
|           |           |           |
|- 1. word -|- 2. word -|- 3. word -|
```

There are following noteworthy details:

- the memory is contiguous and direct.
- every element is 4 byte long, the strings are saved without NUL-terminator (see 2.word), this information is not really needed.
- if a word is less than 4 characters long, the remaining characters must be set to `\0`, i.e. NUL-character. One is out of luck if one wants to store strings with trailing `\0` - but this is another story.

A `std::vector<std::string>` has a completely different memory layout - and because the memory layout of `std::string` isn't prescribed via C++-standard, it can change from implementation to implementation.

The result of the above observations, is there is no way around copying the data if strings are given as `std::vector<std::string>`. The function consists of three steps:

- allocate memory
- copy strings to the new location
- create numpy-array from the above constructed memory.

Below is an example implementation for C++11, in which error handling is left as an exercise for the reader:

```
PyObject* create_np_array(const std::vector<std::string> vals, size_t itemsize){

    //1. step allocate memory
    size_t mem_size = vals.size()*itemsize;
    void * mem = PyDataMem_NEW(mem_size);
    //ToDo: check mem!=nullptr
    //ToDo: make code exception safe

    //2. step initialize memory/copy data:
    size_t cur_index=0;
    for(const auto& val : vals){
        for(size_t i=0;i<itemsize;i++){
            char ch = i<val.size() ?  
                      val[i] : 
                      0; //fill with NUL if string too short
            reinterpret_cast<char*>(mem)[cur_index] = ch;
            cur_index++;
        }
    }

    //3. create numpy array
    npy_intp dim = static_cast<npy_intp>(vals.size());         
    return (PyObject*)PyArray_New(&PyArray_Type, 1, &dim, NPY_STRING, NULL, mem, 4, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA, NULL);
```

One last important thing: one should use `PyDataMem_NEW` to allocate data instead of `malloc`, if it should be owned by the resulting numpy-array (`NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA` - flag). This has two advantages: the memory tracing works correctly and we don't (mis)use an implementation detail. For other ways to pass ownership of the data, see this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55959886/5769463).