# How to convert an array of C structs to a numpy array using Cython

Tags: c, numpy, cython

I'm trying to create a Python module that converts an array of C structs returned from a C shared library, to a Numpy array. I'm new to both Numpy and Cython (but have doing C a long time), so I've been kind of learning as I go.
A few notes:
1) the C shared library, called HBtrial, is in a different directory
2) the C code calloc()'s the memory, fills in the structs and returns a pointer to the array of structs
3) I need the returned array to be a Numpy array (preferably a structured array that will probably then be converted to a Pandas Dataframe)

After trying a number of things, I got the farthest (including getting the .pyx file to compile) by doing the following.

**trial.pyx**

```
import cython
from cpython.ref cimport PyTypeObject
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
cimport HBtrial


cdef extern from "numpy/ndarrayobject.h":
    object PyArray_NewFromDescr(PyTypeObject *subtype,
        np.dtype newdtype,
        int nd,
        np.npy_intp* dims,
        np.npy_intp* strides,
        void* data,
        int flags,
        object parent)

np.import_array()

class MyStruct(object):
    dtype_mystruct = np.dtype ([('item', 'S16'),
                                ('date', 'S16'),
                                ('val1', 'u1'),
                                ('val2', 'u1'),
                                ('val3', 'i2')
                               ])

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def return_dtype(self):
        return self.dtype_mystruct

    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    def return_values(self):
        cdef int rows
        cdef HBtrial.MYSTRUCT *arr = HBtrial.return_values(&rows)

        print arr[1]
        print "npy array"
        cdef np.npy_intp dims = rows

        nparr = np.PyArray_NewFromDescr(np.ndarray,
                                        self.dtype_mystruct,
                                        1,
                                        dims,
                                        <object>NULL,
                                        <object><void *>arr,
                                        0,
                                        <object>NULL)

        print nparr[1]
        return nparr
```

It compiles okay, but then I try to use it in the small Python script as follows:

**try.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import numpy as np

from trial import MyStruct

def main():
    mystruct = MyStruct()
    dt = mystruct.return_dtype()
    print dt
    arr = mystruct.return_values()
    print arr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run it, it prints out the "print dt" line fine, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./try.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "./try.py", line 14, in main
    arr = mystruct.return_values()
  File "trial.pyx", line 43, in trial.MyStruct.return_values (trial.c:1569)
    nparr = np.PyArray_NewFromDescr(np.ndarray,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PyArray_NewFromDescr'
```

**How do I get past this error?**
I feel like I'm maybe missing something basic. Any ideas? If I'm totally off base in my approach, let me know that, too.

Here are the other files, if it helps:

**trial.pxd:**

```
from libc.stdint cimport int8_t, int16_t, uint8_t, uint16_t

cdef extern from "HBtrial.h" nogil:

    ctypedef packed struct MYSTRUCT:
        char item[16];
        char date[16];
        uint8_t val1;
        uint8_t val2;
        int16_t val3;

    cdef MYSTRUCT *return_values(int *rows)
```

**HBtrial.h:**

```
#ifndef HBTRIAL_H
#define HBTRIAL_H

typedef struct {
    char item[16];
    char date[16];
    uint8_t val1;
    uint8_t val2;
    int16_t val3;
} MYSTRUCT;

MYSTRUCT *return_values(int *rows);

#endif
```

**HBtrial.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "HBtrial.h"

MYSTRUCT *return_values(int *rows)
{
    int i;
    MYSTRUCT *arr;
    int numrows = 5;

    arr = calloc(numrows, sizeof(MYSTRUCT));

    for (i=0; i < numrows; i++) {
        sprintf(arr[i].item, "row%d", i);
        sprintf(arr[i].date, "201908100%d", i+1);
        arr[i].val1 = i+2;
        arr[i].val2 = i+i;
        arr[i].val3 = i*i;
    }
    *rows = numrows;
    return(arr);
}
```

HBtrial.c and HBtrial.h are in /home/xxxx/lib/try3 and get compiled into a shared library, "libHBtrial.so".

**setup.py:**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

trial = Extension(
    name="trial",
    sources=["trial.pyx"],
    extra_compile_args=["-std=c99"],
    libraries=["HBtrial"],
    library_dirs=["/home/xxxx/lib/try3"],
    include_dirs=[np.get_include(), "/home/xxxx/lib/try3"]
)

setup(
    name="trial",
    ext_modules=cythonize([trial])
)
```

If there's a better way, I'd be interested in that, too. For instance, I tried other things like converting the returned array to a Cython typed memoryview, or using np.frombuffer(), but always got an error that it `"Cannot convert MYSTRUCT * to"` a memoryview or python object or whatever.

Comment: it is `PyArray_NewFromDescr` not `np.PyArray_NewFromDescr`.

Comment: Then you need to  drop all <object> in arguments of `PyArray_NewFromDescr` as well.

Comment: @ead I tried that. It fails to compile with an error of `undeclared name not builtin: PyArray_NewFromDescr`. Am I missing an import or something? It doesn't seem to know about things I would think it ought to.

Comment: If I were doing it I'd probably try to [implement the Python buffer protocol](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/buffer.html): create a cdef class that manages the memory from `return_values` and implements `__getbuffer__`. You should be able to pass that straight to Numpy (Python API, rather than C API).

Comment: You have also another problem: a possible memory leak, because who owns `arr`? See a somewhere related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55959886/5769463

Comment: @DavidW I doubt implementing buffer protocol is easier than figuring out how to correctly call `PyArray_NewFromDescr`

Comment: @bkb105 if you see this error, then your code isn't the code presented in the question (see `cdef extern from ...` block). However, you have another problems in how you call `PyArray_NewFromDescr`, e.g. `np.ndarray` isn't of type `PyTypeObject *`.

Comment: @ead - no, I don't think it's easier. It does solve the memory management problem (and the associated problem if matching malloc with Numpy's free) and that's why I like it slightly more.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally got it working. Thanks to comments by @ead and something I already had been thinking about, I needed to cdef the call to `PyArray_FromNewDescr` and change a couple arguments.
As part of the "cdef extern..." block I added:

```
PyTypeObject PyArray_Type
```

Then the call to the routine becomes:

```
cdef np.ndarray nparr = PyArray_NewFromDescr(&PyArray_Type,
                                            self.dtype_mystruct,
                                            1,
                                            &dims,
                                            NULL,
                                            <void *>arr,
                                            0,
                                            <object>NULL)
```

Now I can print the array with the proper values on return from routine.
As for the memory leak, based on other posts I found, I should be able to take care of that by setting the OWNDATA flag on the array before I return it, right?