# How to create n-dim numpy array from a pointer?

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I've read about numpy.frombuffer, but can't find any way to create array from pointer.

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708758/can-i-force-a-numpy-ndarray-to-take-ownership-of-its-memory

Answer (score 22):

As pointed out in the comments above, you can use `numpy.ctypeslib.as_array`:

> numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(obj, shape=None)
>
> Create a numpy array from a ctypes array or a ctypes POINTER. The numpy array shares the memory with the ctypes object.
>
> The size parameter must be given if converting from a ctypes POINTER.
>   The size parameter is ignored if converting from a ctypes array

So let's mimic a C function returning a pointer with a call to `malloc`:

```
import ctypes as C
from ctypes.util import find_library
import numpy as np

SIZE = 10

libc = C.CDLL(find_library('c'))
libc.malloc.restype = C.c_void_p

# get a pointer to a block of data from malloc
data_pointer = libc.malloc(SIZE * C.sizeof(C.c_int))
data_pointer = C.cast(data_pointer,C.POINTER(C.c_int))
```

You can now make the data this pointer points to available to numpy

```
new_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(data_pointer,shape=(SIZE,))
```

And to prove that they are accessing the same memory:

```
new_array[:] = range(SIZE)

print "Numpy array:",new_array[:SIZE]
print "Data pointer: ",data_pointer[:SIZE]
```

should output:

```
Numpy array: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
Data pointer:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

As a final note remember that the numpy array does not own its memory so explicit calls to free are required to avoid memory leaks.

```
del new_array
libc.free(data_pointer)
```

Comment: The library may be using a custom allocator, or on Windows in particular it could be linked with a different CRT. In general the library should export a function to `free` memory that it allocates.

Comment: Each call to `as_array` for a new pointer has to create and store an `__array_interface__` on the pointer. I recall a question that complained about the performance of this. Using an array type or a `c_void_p` subclass created by `ndpointer` doesn't have this cost, but it's not as flexible.