# How do I read a C char array into a python bytearray with cython?

Tags: cython

I have an array with bytes and its size:

```
cdef char *bp
cdef size_t size
```

How do I read the array into a Python bytearray (or another appropriate structure that can easily be pickled)?

Comment: Seems like it should be really straightforward, but I tried googling for 30 minutes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23934417/992687

Comment: I guess there should be a way to do this without numpy or ctypes?

Comment: ctypes.string_at(address, size=-1) seems to be the way to do it then...

Comment: There's a Python C API function (I think PyBytes_FromStringAndSize) that can be called from Cython. Don't have time now, but if that isn't enough of a start for you to fix it yourself I'll write an answer later.

Comment: David W: I am using the char array to store arbitrary binary data. Will PyBytes_FromStringAndSize work then?

Comment: Yes. It should work fine.

Comment: @DavidW: This should give you more background on what I am trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50230972/pointer-returned-by-open-memstream-represented-as-b-in-python (when and if you want to reply).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three reasonably straightforward ways to do it:

1. Use the appropriate C API function as I suggested in the comments:

   ```
    from cpython.bytes cimport PyBytes_FromStringAndSize

    output = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(bp,size)
   ```

   This makes a copy, which may be an issue with a sufficiently large string. For Python 2 the functions are similarly named but with `PyString` rather than `PyBytes`.
2. View the char pointer with a typed memoryview, get a numpy array from that:

   ```
   cdef char[::1] mview = <char[:size:1]>(bp)
   output = np.asarray(mview)
   ```

   This shouldn't make a copy, so could be more efficient if large.
3. Do the copy manually:

   ```
    output = bytearray(size)
    for i in range(size):
        output[i] = bp[i]
   ```

   (this could be somewhat accelerated with Cython if needed)

---

This issue I think you're having with ctypes (based on the subsequent question you linked to in the comments) is that you cannot pass C pointer to the ctypes Python interface. If you try to pass a `char*` to a Python function Cython will try to convert it to a string. This fails because it stops at the first 0 element (hence you need size). Therefore you aren't passing ctypes a `char*`, you're passing it a nonsense Python string.

Comment: Your comment below the line seems correct. Perhaps add it as an answer there to help future newbs? Also I'd accept and upvote :) Thanks for all your help, if you want to be credited in my published package please tell me.

Comment: I've posted an answer to the other question (although I'd guess this question will be more useful to future people than the other one). I don't really think I need to be credited. Thanks for the offer though.