# Pointer returned by open_memstream represented as b'' in Cython

Tags: cython

I have the following cython code in a cdef object:

```
def __getstate__(self):

    cdef char *bp
    cdef size_t size
    cdef cn.FILE *stream

    stream = cn.open_memstream(&bp, &size)

    cn.write_padded_binary(self.im, self.n, 256, stream)
    cn.fflush(stream);

    cn.fclose(stream)

    print("pointer", bp, "size_t:", size)
    # ('pointer', b'', 'size_t:', 6144)
    bt = c.string_at(bp, size)
    print("bt", bt)

    cn.free(bp)

    return bt
```

However, the pointer printed in `print("pointer", bp, "size_t:", size)` and the bytestring that is printed in `print("bt", bt)` makes me worried that something is wrong. The pointer is just `('pointer', b'', 'size_t:', 6144)` and the bytestring seems to contain text from Python source code:

> x00\x00 Normalize an encoding name.\n\n        Normalization works as
>   follows: all non-alphanumeric\n        characters except the dot used
>   for Python package names are\n        collapsed and replaced with a
>   single underscore, e.g. \'  -;#\'\n        becomes \'_\'. Leading and
>   trailing underscores are removed.\n\n        Note that encoding names
>   should be ASCII only; if they do use\n        non-ASCII characters,
>   these must be Latin-1 compatible.\n\n    \x00\x00\

(It's mostly just byte-symbols though).

I am sure the `write_padded_binary_works`, because it works when I give it a regular file descriptor. I am also sure open_memstream works because when I try it with `cn.fprintf(stream, "hello");` instead of the `write_padded_binary` the output is `('bt', b'hello')`. However, the pointer is also `('pointer', b'hello', 'size_t:', 5)` so I must be misunderstanding something pointer-related I think...

Comment: open_memstream described in libc manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Streams.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having (diagnosed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50232157/4657412)) is that you can't pass a `char*` directly to Python functions. When you do Cython attempts to convert it into a string (which doesn't make sense because it's just holding binary data, so interpreting it as a null terminated C string causes it to read an arbitrary length until it finds a 0.

This cases issues with both `print` and `ctypes.string_at`. The trick in both cases is to cast it to an appropriately sized integer first. The C `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be large enough to hold an integer, so is the appropriate choice:

```
from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t

print("pointer", <uintptr_t>bp, "size_t:", size)
bt = c.string_at(<uintptr_t>bp, size)
```