# Converting float array to numpy array in Python

Tags: c++, python, arrays, numpy, floating-point

I have a library in C++ which I import in Python language. This library has a method that returns a float32 2D matrix (pointer), but I previously used a numpy array to represent this matrix. Now that I have this matrix made in C++ I can't use the methods of numpy library correctly. So is there any way of importing this matrix allocated in C++ to a numpy object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your question was already answered here, in a more general sense. You need to use `numpy.frombuffer` to create the array from the C++ pointer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355524/getting-data-from-ctypes-array-into-numpy