# which type of ctype pointer to pass to NI IMAQ's imgBayerColorDecode?

Tags: python, ctypes, labview

I'm using ctypes to access the image acquisition API from National Instruments (NI-IMAQ). In it, there's a function called `imgBayerColorDecode()` which I'm using on a Bayer encoded image returned from the `imgSnap()` function. I would like to compare the decoded output (that is an RGB image) to some numpy ndarrays that I will create based on the raw data, which is what imgSnap returns.

However, there are 2 problems.

The first is simple: passing the imgbuffer returned by imgSnap into a numpy array. Now first of all there's a catch: if your machine is 64-bit and you have more than 3GB of RAM, you cannot create the array with numpy and pass it as a pointer to imgSnap. That's why you have to implement a workaround, which is described on NI's forums ([NI ref - first 2 posts](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Machine-Vision/Using-NI-IMAQ-imgSnap-ANSI-C-with-Windows-7-x64/td-p/1078765)): disable an error message (line 125 in the code attached below: `imaq.niimaquDisable32bitPhysMemLimitEnforcement`) and ensure that it is the IMAQ library that creates the memory required for the image (`imaq.imgCreateBuffer`). After that, [this recipe on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355524/getting-data-from-ctypes-array-into-numpy) should be able to convert the buffer into a numpy array again. But I'm unsure if I made the correct changes to the datatypes: the camera has 1020x1368 pixels, each pixel intensity is recorded with 10 bits of precision. It returns the image over a CameraLink and I'm assuming it does this with 2 bytes per pixel, for ease of data transportation. Does this mean I have to adapt the recipe given in the other SO question:

```
buffer = numpy.core.multiarray.int_asbuffer(ctypes.addressof(y.contents), 8*array_length)
a = numpy.frombuffer(buffer, float)
```

to this:

```
bufsize = 1020*1368*2
buffer = numpy.core.multiarray.int_asbuffer(ctypes.addressof(y.contents), bufsize)
a = numpy.frombuffer(buffer, numpy.int16)
```

The second problem is that imgBayerColorDecode() does not give me an output I'm expecting.
Below are 2 images, the first being the output of imgSnap, saved with `imgSessionSaveBufferEx()`. The second is the output of imgSnap after it has gone through the demosaicing of imgBayerColorDecode().

- raw data: i42.tinypic.com/znpr38.jpg
- bayer decoded: i39.tinypic.com/n12nmq.jpg

As you can see, the bayer decoded image is still a grayscale and moreover it does not resemble the original image (small remark here, the images were scaled for upload with imagemagick). The original image was taken with a red color filter in front of some mask. From it (and 2 other color filters), I know that the Bayer color filter looks like this in the top left corner:

```
BGBG
GRGR
```

I believe I'm doing something wrong in passing the correct type of pointer to imgBayerDecode, my code is appended below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division

import ctypes as C
import ctypes.util as Cutil
import time


# useful references:
# location of the niimaq.h: C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\NI-IMAQ\Include
# location of the camera files: C:\Users\Public\Documents\National Instruments\NI-IMAQ\Data
# check it C:\Users\Public\Documents\National Instruments\NI-IMAQ\Examples\MSVC\Color\BayerDecode

class IMAQError(Exception):
    """A class for errors produced during the calling of National Intrument's IMAQ functions.
    It will also produce the textual error message that corresponds to a specific code."""

    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code
        text = C.c_char_p('')
        imaq.imgShowError(code, text)
        self.message = "{}: {}".format(self.code, text.value)
        # Call the base class constructor with the parameters it needs
        Exception.__init__(self, self.message)


def imaq_error_handler(code):
    """Print the textual error message that is associated with the error code."""

    if code < 0:
        raise IMAQError(code)
        free_associated_resources = 1
        imaq.imgSessionStopAcquisition(sid)
        imaq.imgClose(sid, free_associated_resources)
        imaq.imgClose(iid, free_associated_resources)
    else:
        return code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    imaqlib_path = Cutil.find_library('imaq')
    imaq = C.windll.LoadLibrary(imaqlib_path)


    imaq_function_list = [  # this is not an exhaustive list, merely the ones used in this program
        imaq.imgGetAttribute,
        imaq.imgInterfaceOpen,
    imaq.imgSessionOpen,
        imaq.niimaquDisable32bitPhysMemLimitEnforcement,  # because we're running on a 64-bit machine with over 3GB of RAM
        imaq.imgCreateBufList,
        imaq.imgCreateBuffer,
        imaq.imgSetBufferElement,
        imaq.imgSnap,
        imaq.imgSessionSaveBufferEx,
        imaq.imgSessionStopAcquisition,
        imaq.imgClose,
        imaq.imgCalculateBayerColorLUT,
        imaq.imgBayerColorDecode ]

    # for all imaq functions we're going to call, we should specify that if they
    # produce an error (a number), we want to see the error message (textually)
    for func in imaq_function_list:
        func.restype = imaq_error_handler




    INTERFACE_ID = C.c_uint32
    SESSION_ID = C.c_uint32
    BUFLIST_ID = C.c_uint32
    iid = INTERFACE_ID(0)
    sid = SESSION_ID(0)
    bid = BUFLIST_ID(0)
    array_16bit = 2**16 * C.c_uint32
    redLUT, greenLUT, blueLUT  = [ array_16bit() for _ in range(3) ]
    red_gain, blue_gain, green_gain = [ C.c_double(val) for val in (1., 1., 1.) ]

    # OPEN A COMMUNICATION CHANNEL WITH THE CAMERA
    # our camera has been given its proper name in Measurement & Automation Explorer (MAX)
    lcp_cam = 'JAI CV-M7+CL'
    imaq.imgInterfaceOpen(lcp_cam, C.byref(iid))
    imaq.imgSessionOpen(iid, C.byref(sid)); 

    # START C MACROS DEFINITIONS
    # define some C preprocessor macros (these are all defined in the niimaq.h file)
    _IMG_BASE = 0x3FF60000

    IMG_BUFF_ADDRESS = _IMG_BASE + 0x007E  # void *
    IMG_BUFF_COMMAND = _IMG_BASE + 0x007F  # uInt32
    IMG_BUFF_SIZE = _IMG_BASE + 0x0082  #uInt32
    IMG_CMD_STOP = 0x08  # single shot acquisition

    IMG_ATTR_ROI_WIDTH = _IMG_BASE + 0x01A6
    IMG_ATTR_ROI_HEIGHT = _IMG_BASE + 0x01A7
    IMG_ATTR_BYTESPERPIXEL = _IMG_BASE + 0x0067  
    IMG_ATTR_COLOR = _IMG_BASE + 0x0003  # true = supports color
    IMG_ATTR_PIXDEPTH = _IMG_BASE + 0x0002  # pix depth in bits
    IMG_ATTR_BITSPERPIXEL = _IMG_BASE + 0x0066 # aka the bit depth

    IMG_BAYER_PATTERN_GBGB_RGRG = 0
    IMG_BAYER_PATTERN_GRGR_BGBG = 1
    IMG_BAYER_PATTERN_BGBG_GRGR = 2
    IMG_BAYER_PATTERN_RGRG_GBGB = 3
    # END C MACROS DEFINITIONS

    width, height = C.c_uint32(), C.c_uint32()
    has_color, pixdepth, bitsperpixel, bytes_per_pixel = [ C.c_uint8() for _ in range(4) ]

    # poll the camera (or is it the camera file (icd)?) for these attributes and store them in the variables
    for var, macro in [ (width, IMG_ATTR_ROI_WIDTH), 
                        (height, IMG_ATTR_ROI_HEIGHT),
                        (bytes_per_pixel, IMG_ATTR_BYTESPERPIXEL),
                        (pixdepth, IMG_ATTR_PIXDEPTH),
                        (has_color, IMG_ATTR_COLOR),
                        (bitsperpixel, IMG_ATTR_BITSPERPIXEL) ]:
        imaq.imgGetAttribute(sid, macro, C.byref(var))  


    print("Image ROI size: {} x {}".format(width.value, height.value))
    print("Pixel depth: {}\nBits per pixel: {} -> {} bytes per pixel".format(
        pixdepth.value, 
        bitsperpixel.value, 
        bytes_per_pixel.value))

    bufsize = width.value*height.value*bytes_per_pixel.value
    imaq.niimaquDisable32bitPhysMemLimitEnforcement(sid)

    # create the buffer (in a list)
    imaq.imgCreateBufList(1, C.byref(bid))  # Creates a buffer list with one buffer

    # CONFIGURE THE PROPERTIES OF THE BUFFER
    imgbuffer = C.POINTER(C.c_uint16)()  # create a null pointer
    RGBbuffer = C.POINTER(C.c_uint32)()  # placeholder for the Bayer decoded imgbuffer (i.e. demosaiced imgbuffer)
    imaq.imgCreateBuffer(sid, 0, bufsize, C.byref(imgbuffer))  # allocate memory (the buffer) on the host machine (param2==0)
    imaq.imgCreateBuffer(sid, 0, width.value*height.value * 4, C.byref(RGBbuffer))

    imaq.imgSetBufferElement(bid, 0, IMG_BUFF_ADDRESS, C.cast(imgbuffer, C.POINTER(C.c_uint32)))  # my guess is that the cast to an uint32 is necessary to prevent 64-bit callable memory addresses
    imaq.imgSetBufferElement(bid, 0, IMG_BUFF_SIZE, bufsize)
    imaq.imgSetBufferElement(bid, 0, IMG_BUFF_COMMAND, IMG_CMD_STOP)

    # CALCULATE THE LOOKUP TABLES TO CONVERT THE BAYER ENCODED IMAGE TO RGB (=DEMOSAICING)
    imaq.imgCalculateBayerColorLUT(red_gain, green_gain, blue_gain, redLUT, greenLUT, blueLUT, bitsperpixel)


    # CAPTURE THE RAW DATA 

    imgbuffer_vpp = C.cast(C.byref(imgbuffer), C.POINTER(C.c_void_p))
    imaq.imgSnap(sid, imgbuffer_vpp)
    #imaq.imgSnap(sid, imgbuffer)  # <- doesn't work (img produced is entirely black). The above 2 lines are required
    imaq.imgSessionSaveBufferEx(sid, imgbuffer,"bayer_mosaic.png")
    print('1 taken')


    imaq.imgBayerColorDecode(RGBbuffer, imgbuffer, height, width, width, width, redLUT, greenLUT, blueLUT, IMG_BAYER_PATTERN_BGBG_GRGR, bitsperpixel, 0) 
    imaq.imgSessionSaveBufferEx(sid,RGBbuffer,"snapshot_decoded.png");

    free_associated_resources = 1
    imaq.imgSessionStopAcquisition(sid)
    imaq.imgClose(sid, free_associated_resources )
    imaq.imgClose(iid, free_associated_resources )
    print "Finished"
```

---

Follow-up: after a discussion with an [NI representative](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Machine-Vision/NI-IMAQ-s-imgBayerColorDecode-to-output-64-bit-RGB-images/td-p/2460682), I am getting convinced that the second issue is due to imgBayerColorDecode being limited to 8bit input images prior to its 2012 release (we are working on 2010). However, I would like to confirm this: if I cast the 10-bit image to an 8-bit image, keeping only the most significant bytes, and passing this cast version to imgBayerColorDecode, I'm expecting to see an RGB image.

To do so, I am casting the imgbuffer to a numpy array and shifting the 10-bit data with 2 bits:

```
np_buffer = np.core.multiarray.int_asbuffer(
    ctypes.addressof(imgbuffer.contents), bufsize)
flat_data = np.frombuffer(np_buffer, np.uint16)

# from 10 bit to 8 bit, keeping only the non-empty bytes
Z = (flat_data>>2).view(dtype='uint8')[::2] 
Z2 = Z.copy()  # just in case
```

Now I pass the ndarray Z2 to imgBayerColorDecode:

```
bitsperpixel = 8
imaq.imgBayerColorDecode(RGBbuffer, Z2.ctypes.data_as(
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8)), height, width, 
    width, width, redLUT, greenLUT, blueLUT, 
    IMG_BAYER_PATTERN_BGBG_GRGR, bitsperpixel, 0)
```

Remark that the original code (shown way above) has been altered slightly, such that redLUt, greenLUT and blueLUT are now only 256 element arrays.
And finally I call `imaq.imgSessionSaveBufferEx(sid,RGBbuffer, save_path)`. But it is still a grayscale and the img shape is not preserved, so I am still doing something terribly wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Oliver. Thanks for posting this code. I am trying to get it working on a different camera. For `lcp_cam`, I have tried various strings I see in MAX, but none of them seem to be the right choice. How did you set that in MAX (or find the right value in MAX)?

Comment: Dan, I found ours in the MAX GUI: in the left panel `My System > Devices and Interfaces > NI-IMAQ Devices`. All cameras linked to the system are listed there, usually in the format `<Manufacturer> <Model>: <NI board>`. In the main panel will appear the *Device Description*, listing also the interface name (which usually has the format `<Manufacturer> <Model>`. You could also find all camera files under `C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\National Instruments\NI-IMAQ\Data` (Windows 7), so it might be worth having a look in there if you can't find your camera through MAX.

Comment: Ah, I was using the camera file name where I should have used the interface name. Success. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of playing around, it turns out that the RGBbuffer mentioned must hold the correct data, but `imgSessionSaveBufferEx` is doing something odd at that point.

When I pass the data from RGBbuffer back to numpy, reshape this 1D-array into the dimension of the image and then split it into color channels by masking and using bitshift operations (e.g. `red_channel = (np_RGB & 0XFF000000)>>16`), I can then save it as a nice color image in png format with PIL or pypng.

I haven't found out why imgSessionSaveBufferEx behaves oddly though, but the solution above works (even though speed-wise it's really inefficient).