# Python `ctypes` - How to copy buffer returned by C function into a bytearray

Tags: python, ctypes

A pointer to buffer of type `POINTER(c_ubyte)` is returned by the C function (the `image_data` variable in the following code). I want this data to be managed by Python, so I want to copy it into a `bytearray`. Here's the function call

```
image_data = stb_image.stbi_load(filename_cstr, byref(width),
                                 byref(height), byref(num_channels), 
                                 c_int(expected_num_channels))
```

We get to know the `width` and `height` of the image only after that call, so can't pre-allocate a `bytearray`.

I would have used

```
 array_type = c.c_ubyte * (num_channels.value * width.value * height.value)

 image_data_bytearray = bytearray(cast(image_data, array_type))
```

But the type to `cast` to must be a pointer, not array, so I get an error.

```
TypeError: cast() argument 2 must be a pointer type, not c_ubyte_Array_262144
```

What should I do?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355524/getting-data-from-ctypes-array-into-numpy - NumPy is a good library for this type of data handling.

Comment: You can have a pointer to an array, e.g. `ptype = POINTER(c_ubyte * (num_channels.value * width.value * height.value))`. Get an instance by copying the address from the source pointer using `from_buffer`, and then dereference to get an array that you can pass to `bytearray`, e.g. `image_data_bytearray = bytearray(ptype.from_buffer(image_data)[0])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, reading the answer to the question linked to in the comments (thanks, @"John Zwinck" and @"eryksun"), there are two ways of storing the data, either in a `bytearray` or a `numpy.array`. In all these snippets, `image_data` is of type `POINTER(c_ubyte)`, and we have `array_type` defined as -

```
array_type = c_ubyte * num_channels * width * height
```

We can create a bytearray first and then loop over and set the bytes

```
arr_bytes = bytearray(array_size)
for i in range(array_size):
    arr_bytes[i] = image_data[i]
```

---

Or a better way is to create a C array instance using `from_address` and then initialize a `bytearray` with it -

```
image_data_carray = array_type.from_address(addressof(image_data.contents))

# Copy into bytearray
image_data_bytearray = bytearray(image_data_carray)
```

And during writing the image (didn't ask this question, just sharing for completeness), we can obtain pointer to the bytearray data like this and give it to `stbi_write_png`

```
image_data_carray = array_type.from_buffer(image_data_bytearray)
image_data = cast(image_data_carray, POINTER(c_ubyte))
```

---

The `numpy` based way of doing it is as answered in the linked question

```
address = addressof(image_data.contents)
image_data_ptr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(array_type.from_address(address))
```

This alone however only points to the memory returned by the C function, doesn't copy into a Python-managed array object. We can copy by creating a numpy array as

```
image_data = np.array(image_data_ptr)
```

To confirm I have done an `assert all(arr_np == arr_bytes)` there. And `arr_np.dtype` is `uint8`.

And during writing the image, we can obtain a pointer to the numpy array's data like this

```
image_data = image_data_numpy.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_ubyte))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable array_type shouldn't even be called thus as it is in fact not an initialized C array nor any kind of type, but a Python object prepared for doing the array initialization.
Well, initialized array also shouldn't be called thus as well. :D

You should be doing there an equivalent of:

```
unsigned char array[channels*width*height];
```

in C. Then array is a pointer to N*types unsigned char pointing to first byte of the array. (index 0)
A cast() should get a pointer to see the data's type,. So doing:

```
array = (c.c_ubyte*(channels*width*height))()
```

should do the trick. But you don't need extra allocated memory. So you can create a pointer as suggested in a comment.

But I suggest you use:

```
image_data = bytearray(c.string_at(image_data))
```

It should work, assuming, of course, that returned image is null terminated. Well, this also implies using signed chars but it doesn't have to be.
If you wrote the C portion, just allocate one byte extra to the memory that will contain an image which is declared/cast to contain unsigned chars and put the last item to 0.
Then leave the algorithm to work as before. If you do not null terminate it, you will still get the whole image with string_at(), but there will be a memory leak of 3 bytes or so more. Very undesirable.

I used this trick in my C module for colorspace conversion. It works extremely fast as there are no loops, No anything extra. string_at() just pulls in the buffer and creates Python string wrapper around it.
Then you can use numpy.fromstring(...) or array.array("B", image_data) or use bytearray() as above  etc.

Otherwise, well, I saw your answer just now. You can do it as you wrote as well, but I think that my dirty trick is better (if you can change the C code, of course).

P.S. Whoops! I just saw in a **doc** string that string_at() can have an optional argument size. Perhaps using it will completely ignore the termination and there wouldn't be any leakage. I am asking myself now why didn't I use it in my project but messed with null termination.
Perhaps out of lazyness. Using size shouldn't require any modifications to C code. So it would be:

```
image_data = bytearray(c.string_at(image_data, channels*width*height))
```